# I had an html comment in a Django template, and it was causing a server error when DEBUG=False, why?

Tags: django, django-templates

Previously I had a favicon.png, I deleted the favicon.png file.  This did not create any issues until I switched from DEBUG = True to DEBUG = False in my settings.py file. And I got a 500 server error.

To diagnose the issue I added DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True to my settings.py
And I got the following error:
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.png'

Only place where there was even a mention of 'favicon.png' was as an html comment in my login html template file, login.html contained the following in head:

```
  <title>Login</title>
 <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}"/> -->
```

when I deleted the favicon.png html comment so that code became:

```
<title>Login</title>
```

I no longer got a 500 server error, and things worked again.

How can an html comment cause an error in my code? I thought it was impossible for an html comment to cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}"/> -->
```

will be commented out when the page is rendered, but when the html template is constructed, Django will still try to execute `{% static 'favicon.png' %}` because *template languages don't understand html*, which includes, but is not limited to, html comments.

Template languages need to decide what special characters it will use, and it **can't** use special html characters, because it wouldn't be able to distinguish between what is html code, and what is template code.

So in the case of django, `<!` is not a *"special symbol"* in the template language, so it is ignored, while `{%` is a *"special symbol"*, so code within that block will be executed.

If you want to comment this out, you can do either of the following:

```
{% comment %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}"/>
{% endcomment %}

{% # <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.png' %}"/> %}
```

### Edit

Here is a snippet from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) that is related to your issue:

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
>
> See Deploying static files for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments

This leads me to suspect that your `settings.py` is not properly configured for deployment.

Comment: I assume it is ok to use html comments in a django template as long as the html comment does not have any {% special symbols within it?

Comment: @Padoga Yes to the first comment, and I'm looking into the second.

Comment: @Padoga I wasn't able to recreate your error message, but I think it has something to do with your `settings.py` not being configured to serve static files in production.  See [deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/#deploying-static-files) for a step by step guide for deploying.